# Minhag hamakom, minhag avot, tefillah in synagogue, minhag at home

Tags: tefilla, minhag, synagogue, family-members

We suppose that a Jew lives in a city where there are synagogues that follow his minhag avot, but in that city there are also synagogues that do not follow his minhag avot. Halakhically, can he do the 3 daily tefillot in the synagogue that does not follow his minhag avot, but follow his minhag avot at home?

Answer (score 2):

You can daven in a shul that does not follow your nusach. Just use your nusach for pesukei d'zimra and shemona esrai unless you are davening for the amud in which case follow the nusach of the shul. Lots of people do this.

Comment: Agreed that this happens often; Rav Moshe Feinstein gives the option of either doing everything the way the shul does it, or doing the out-loud parts the way the shul does it. (Though a non-Chassid at a Nusach Sfard shul should say Bameh Madlikin and not Kegavna, as it's quiet and not a "prayer" per se.) I *think* the question is if someone has the option of two shuls, one their nusach one not, can they plan to just-about-always daven at the other-nusach place. (What makes that shul so much better?) I'd say nusach should be a serious factor when weighing shuls, but ...

Comment: ... it would be hard to say "it's prohibited." (Say someone's Ashkenazi but finds they can focus far, far better at an Edot haMizrach place ... okay, fine...) But if someone *really* feels much more at home in a community with a different nusach, it's not crazy to just take on that nusach full-time -- especially if they're baal teshuva.

Comment: The typical question is someone who winds up at an other-Nusach place because it's the only game in town, or they're traveling, or the time and location fit their schedule far better. (I could see someone picking a favorite shul shabbos morning because of the kiddush ... but why would they keep going there three prayers a day on weekdays too?)